# Finding requested big-o ( log(n) ) for the following question

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

suppose we have a increasingly sorted array with n elements , and someone right-rotated this array for k times , ( n > k ) , i want to find an algorithm with log(n) bog-O ,to find the number of "k" , can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

found it myself I think , by checking all of the possible ways for k we can assume that the k equals to the index of the maximum element in the array , so if we find the index of the maximum element of the array we'll find the answer , with a recursive binary-search we can reach to big-O ( log(n) ) . 
aware me if I'm wrong :)

[check out the all possible ways for k , x: indexs y:elemnents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk7kC.png)